# Iterate a simple calculation in Pandas across multiple files

Tags: python, pandas

The code below generates a sum from the "Value" column in an ndarray called 'File1.csv'.

How do I apply this code to every file in a directory and place the sums in a new file called Sum.csv?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("~/File1.csv")

df["Value"].sum()
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's probably a nice way to do this with a pandas `Panel`, but this is a basic python implementation.

```py
import os 
import pandas as pd

# Get the home directory (not recommended, work somewhere else)
directory = os.environ["HOME"]
# Read all files in directory, filter out non-csv
files = [os.path.join(directory, f) 
         for f in os.listdir(directory) if f.endswith(".csv")] 
# Make list of tuples [(filename, sum)]
sums =  [(filename, pd.read_csv(filename)["Value"].sum())
         for filename in files ]
# Make a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(sums, columns=["filename", "sum"])
df.to_csv(os.path.join(directory, "files_with_sum.csv"))
```

Note that the built in python os.listdir() doesn't understand `"~/"` like pandas does, so we get it out of the environment map.  Using the home directory isn't really recommended, so this gives any adopter of this code an opportunity to set a different path.

Comment: Works. Thank you rocconick!